# Cannot write to an ncurses window using mvwprintw()

Tags: c++, window, ncurses

For days I'm trying to figure out the reason for the problem I have with this code:

```cpp
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

WINDOW *create_newwin(int height, int width, int starty, int startx);
void destroy_win(WINDOW *local_win);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  
    WINDOW *my_win;
    int startx, starty, width, height;
    int ch;

    initscr();              // Start curses mode        
    // cbreak();            // Line buffering en/disabled, pass on
                            // everything to me         
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);   // I need that nifty F2

    height = 3;
    width = 10;
    starty = (LINES - height) / 2;  /* Calculating for a center placement */
    startx = (COLS - width) / 2;    /* of the window        */
    printw("Press F2 to exit!\n");
    refresh();
    my_win = create_newwin(height, width, starty, startx);

    // keypad(my_win, TRUE);

    while((ch = getch()) != KEY_F(2))   {   
        switch(ch) {    
            case KEY_LEFT:
                destroy_win(my_win);
                my_win = create_newwin(height, width, starty,--startx);
                break;
            case KEY_RIGHT:
                destroy_win(my_win);
                my_win = create_newwin(height, width, starty,++startx);
                break;
            case KEY_UP:
                destroy_win(my_win);
                my_win = create_newwin(height, width, --starty,startx);
                break;
            case KEY_DOWN:
                destroy_win(my_win);
                my_win = create_newwin(height, width, ++starty,startx);
                break;
            case 49:
                // Kann nicht in das Fenster my_win ausgeben, Fkt.
                // wird ignoriert:
                mvwprintw(my_win, 1, 1, "Value: %d, H %d, W %d, STy %d, STx %d", 1, height, width, starty, startx);
                cout << "   cout -> Values: height " <<  height  << ", width "<< width <<  ", starty " << starty <<  ", startx " << startx << endl;
                break;  
        }
    }
        
    endwin();           /* End curses mode */
    return 0;
}

WINDOW *create_newwin(int height, int width, int starty, int startx) {  
    WINDOW *local_win;

    local_win = newwin(height, width, starty, startx);
    box(local_win, 0 , 0);      // 0, 0 gives default characters 
                                // for the vertical and horizontal
                                // lines.
    wrefresh(local_win);        // Show that box.

    return local_win;
}

void destroy_win(WINDOW *local_win) {
    /* box(local_win, ' ', ' '); : This won't produce the desired
     * result of erasing the window. It will leave it's four corners 
     * and so an ugly remnant of window. 
     */
    wborder(local_win, ' ', ' ', ' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ');
    /* The parameters taken are 
     * 1. win: the window on which to operate
     * 2. ls: character to be used for the left side of the window 
     * 3. rs: character to be used for the right side of the window 
     * 4. ts: character to be used for the top side of the window 
     * 5. bs: character to be used for the bottom side of the window 
     * 6. tl: character to be used for the top left corner of the window 
     * 7. tr: character to be used for the top right corner of the window 
     * 8. bl: character to be used for the bottom left corner of the window 
     * 9. br: character to be used for the bottom right corner of the window
     */
    wrefresh(local_win);
    delwin(local_win);
}
```

I took this from: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/windows.html.

Everything works as it should, with one exception:

In the case statement `case 49:` which I added, I try to print in the window `my_win`, but the function call is ignored. It has no effect. Instead, the pressed key "1" is printed on the `stdscr`. The `cout` line is just for debugging purposes and is also printed at the current cursor position in `stdscr`.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? Or how to correct my possibly wrong understanding of the code?

Thanks beforehand to everyone!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the definition of a correct initializing sequence which goes like

```
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();   
    intrflush(stdscr, FALSE);
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);   // To receive F2
```

I found out, that the most important thing I did not recognize all the time was a `wrefresh(my_win);` right after the `mvwprintw` line. So, also these print commands need a refresh of the pertinent window, otherwise the change is done but will not appear on screen.

Answer (score 0):

The example is not properly initialized (see [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization)):

```
initscr();              // Start curses mode        
// cbreak();            // Line buffering en/disabled, pass on
                        // everything to me
```

If the program had called [`cbreak`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-cbreak_nocbreak) or [`raw`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-raw_noraw), then the program would receive characters via `getch` immediately.  Since neither was called, it reads line-buffered data (and nothing happens until you press <kbd>*Enter*</kbd>).

Also, since it does not call `noecho`, the input is echoed.

Comment: I've read all the hints you thankfully posted, and I've integrated this sequence into the program: 
` initscr();
 cbreak();
 // raw();
 noecho(); 
 intrflush(stdscr, FALSE);
 keypad(stdscr, TRUE); // To receive F2`
Unfortunately, it still doesn't work, nothing appears in the my_win window. It makes no difference whether I enter just "1" or "1 ENTER".